# Tkinter Dynamic Frames that are Expandable and Collapsible

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the code below which is based on this question here: [Expandable and contracting frame in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141259/expandable-and-contracting-frame-in-tkinter)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Example:
    def __init__(self, root):
        list_1 = ['item_1', 'item_2']
        list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

        for item in list_1 :
            frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=22)
            frame.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
            frame.propagate(0)

            Label(frame, text=item).pack(side=LEFT, anchor=W)
            entry = Entry(frame, width=11)
            entry.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=2, anchor=E)

            var = IntVar()
            var.set(0)

            sub_frame = Frame(root, relief="sunken", width=400, height=22, borderwidth=1)

            toggle_btn = ttk.Checkbutton(frame, width=2, text='+', command=lambda: self.toggle(var, toggle_btn, sub_frame),
                                     variable=var, style='Toolbutton')
            toggle_btn.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=E)

            for item in list_2:
                Label(sub_frame, text=item).pack(side=TOP)

    def toggle(self, show, toggle_button, sub_frame):
        if bool(show.get()):
            sub_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=1)
            sub_frame.propagate(1)
            toggle_button.configure(text='-')
        else:
            sub_frame.forget()
            toggle_button.configure(text='+')

def main():
    root = Tk()
    open = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want here to create two expandable frames from list_1 and fill each with labels from list_2. The two frames should then be expandable and collapsible to show and hide the items from list_2.

The second frame functions correctly, but the first doesn't because it was overwritten by the second frame.

So the code initially gives you this:

[image]

If you click the '+' next to item_1, nothing happens.

If you click the '+' next to item_2, this happens.

[image]

By clicking on the '+' next to item_1, I want the sub_frame to be shown underneath item_1(between item_1 and item_2), just like clicking on the '+' next to item_2 shows the sub_frame underneath it.

Any help on how to get both frames to work correctly? I've read about storing the frames created in a list, however I couldn't get this to work for me.

Many thanks

Comment: I've updated the code and it is complete.

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't [mcve] to the problem you're having. You can narrow it down more.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that the lambda is bound to the variables, but you want it bound to the *values* of the variables at the time that you create the lambda. This is a very, very common mistake when using lambda.

There are many questions and answers on this site related to this problem. Here are a few:

- [Python tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865116/7432)
- [Python lambda closure scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13355233/7432)
- [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2295290/7432)

---

While it is possible to fix your code as written by modifying the use of `lambda`, I suggest that a better solution is to create a new class that represents one collapsible frame. If this new class inherits from `Frame`, you can use it exactly like any other widget.

With that you can eliminate the need to use `lambda`, and makes it much easier to encapsulate everything about a collapsible frame in one object.

For example:

```
class CustomFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label, items):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        header = tk.Frame(self)
        self.sub_frame = tk.Frame(self, relief="sunken",
                                  width=400, height=22, borderwidth=1)
        header.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.sub_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.label = tk.Label(header, text=label)
        self.toggle_btn = ttk.Checkbutton(header, width=2, text="+",
                                          variable=self.var, style='Toolbutton',
                                          command=self.toggle)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(header, width=11)

        self.label.pack(side="left")
        self.toggle_btn.pack(side="left")
        self.entry.pack(side="right", pady=2, anchor="e")
        self.sub_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        for item in items:
            tk.Label(self.sub_frame, text=item).pack(side="top")

        # this sets the initial state
        self.toggle(False)

    def toggle(self, show=None):
        show = self.var.get() if show is None else show
        if show:
            self.sub_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
            self.toggle_btn.configure(text='-')
        else:
            self.sub_frame.forget()
            self.toggle_btn.configure(text='+')
```

With that, your `Example` class becomes trivial, and you can create as many frames as you want:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, root):
        list_1 = ['item_1', 'item_2']
        list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

        for item in list_1:
            frame = CustomFrame(root, item, list_2)
            frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

Note: the above code assumes that `tkinter` and `ttk` are imported like this, which is slightly different than your original code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
toggle_btn = ttk.Checkbutton(frame, width=2, text='+', command=lambda: self.toggle(var, toggle_btn, sub_frame),
                                     variable=var, style='Toolbutton')
```

with:

```
toggle_btn = ttk.Checkbutton(frame, width=2, text='+',
                                     variable=var, style='Toolbutton')
toggle_btn['command'] = lambda a1=var, a2=toggle_btn, a3=sub_frame: self.toggle(a1, a2, a3)
```

See more on [why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865116/7032856).

---

The [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of above issue should at *longest* be:

```
from tkinter import *

class Example:
    def __init__(self, root):
        list_1 = ['item_1', 'item_2']
        list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

        for item in list_1:
            frame = Frame(root)
            frame.pack()

            var = IntVar()
            sub_frame = Frame(root)
            for item in list_2:
                Label(sub_frame, text=item).pack()

            toggle_btn = Checkbutton(frame,
                command=lambda: self.toggle(var, toggle_btn, sub_frame),
                variable=var)
            toggle_btn.pack()

    def toggle(self, show, toggle_button, sub_frame):
        if bool(show.get()):
            sub_frame.pack()
        else:
            sub_frame.forget()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    open = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

If you don't want to overwrite simply use iterable types, such as `list` and `dict`, instead of singular variables for multiple objects such as your frames and labels. Below code generates a dictionary of `frames`, then a dictionary of `labels` for each of the `frames`:

```
import tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_1 = ['item_1', 'item_2']
    list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    root = tk.Tk()

    frames = dict()

    for item in list_1:
        frames[item] = tk.Frame(root)
        frames[item].pack()
        frames[item].labels = dict()
        for text in list_2:
            frames[item].labels[text] = tk.Label(frames[item], text=text)
            frames[item].labels[text].pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How is that an issue? Even if it is, I haven't time to 'solve' that. I've spent most of my time assigned to this question to create its [mcve].

Comment: Many thanks again for your answer. Changing the checkbutton mostly work as now the sub_frame can be ticked to toggle their appearance.

The remaining issue is that both sub_frames are placed at the bottom of the whole frame whenever they are shown. By ticking the first checkbox I'm looking for the sub_frame to appear in the frame directly underneath the first checkbox (Ie between the two checkboxes). Is there a way to do this? I've tried using a dict but I couldn't figure it out. Many thanks

Comment: The easiest solution for that would be to assign them separately to subframes of their own. Check [Bryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48430121/7032856) if you want to do things OOP, which allows much more flexibility.